# Non-lattice Veech groups

Tags: teichmuller-theory, surfaces

I was thinking of Veech surfaces, which are translation surfaces whose stabilizer under the $\mathrm{Sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ action is a lattice in $\mathrm{Sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$. They seem to have been studied and examples of such surfaces are rare and somehow well understood in low genus.

I was wondering what other examples of Veech groups were known? For example do we know explicit examples of translation surfaces whose Veech group is non-elementary but not a lattice?

Thank you for your attention!

Selim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinitely generated Veech groups were discovered by [Curtis McMullen](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02392964) and [Pascal Hubert and Thomas Schmidt](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1084479318). Both results are more-or-less explicit (in describing a specific translation surface whose Veech group is infinitely generated). Hubert and his collaborators have many other results on Veech groups.